# About quotient spaces of dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, dual-spaces

So when looking around online about dual spaces and quotient spaces I found that if $V$ is a Banach space, $Z \subseteq V^*$ is a closed subspace then there is a set $Z^T \subseteq V$ such that $V^* / Z \cong (V/Z^T )^*$. Could anybody perhaps explain to me what this set $Z^T$ exactly is? I could not easily find something about it online, so that is why I am asking if someone here maybe knows more about it.

Comment: I think you must assume $Z$ to be weak$^*$-closed.

Comment: Maybe have a look at "An introduction to Banach space theory, Megginson" section 1.10 dual spaces

Comment: Your $Z^T$ is the orthogonal of $Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z^\top$ is the pre-annihilator of $Z$, i.e.,

$$Z^\top = \{x\in V\colon \langle f,x\rangle = 0\; (f\in Z)\}.$$

To see that indeed we have this identification in the case $Z$ is weak*-closed, note that we may define

Every functional $f\in (V/Z^\top)^*$ canonically defines $\Phi(f)\in V^* / Z$ by
$$\langle \Phi(f) + Z, v  \rangle = \langle f,v+Z^\perp\rangle \quad (v\in V, z\in Z^\top).$$

Comment: If $V=\ell^1$, and $Z=c_0\subseteq \ell^\infty = V^*$, then $Z^\top=\{0\}$, and I think this doesn't work.

Comment: @Ruy, weak*-closedness is required.

Comment: Sure, this is what I said in a comment below the question.  It wold be nice to emphasize where is this hypothesis used.

Comment: I do not see where the inner product you are using comes from, I mean we are talking about Banach spaces and not necessarily Hilbert spaces? Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean by $\langle f, x \rangle$

Comment: @Tipeg, this is the standardish notation for duality pairing that makes life easier. In principal, $\langle f,x\rangle = f(x)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!